# summary(), anova() type 3, Anova() type 3 not producing similar results for lmer model

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme

First off, I have read a plethora of answers on this site but can't seem to find something that satisfies my situation below:

```
library(lme4)

> dput(test2)
structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), .Label = c("153", "204", 
"212", "790", "1422", "1427", "1430", "1507", "1508", "1511", 
"1512", "1602", "1609", "1618", "5327", "5466", "5753", "5935", 
"6424", "7004", "8339", "10806", "12802"), class = "factor"), 
    Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Con", "Sub", "Cl"), class = "factor"), 
    Stim = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    Treatment = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("None", "V2", "V1"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(2.056, 5.819, 5.371, 15.264, 8.942, 7.934, 9.616, 
    7.752, 6.362, 1.416, 4.82, 5.394, 6.053, 3.23, 3.866, 1.334, 
    1.152, 1.152, 2.165, 2.267, 2.662, 6.26, 3.153, 5.022, 2.455, 
    1.023, 1.239, 4.024, 7.428, 41.86, 9.878, 9.313, 10.056, 
    4.729, 4.776, 1.514, 3.085, 3.845, 5.605, 5.411, 4.991, 1.771, 
    1.418, 2.934, 19.516, 11.404, 11.081, 30.123, 13.1, 13.57, 
    1.612, 0.903, 1.622, 3.293, 1.23, 1.277, 2.185, 4.405, 5.247, 
    22.581, 8.429, 7.529, 7.651, 6.508, 8.511, 1.427, 1.719, 
    1.884, 1.502, 1.436, 2.026, 0.376, 0.631, 0.284, 2.653, 2.307, 
    1.416, 15.086, 5.152, 2.666, 10.176, 3.574, 3.349, 6.896, 
    4.051, 5.826, 14.228, 6.891, 5.277, 10.309, 4.732, 7.404, 
    2.054, 2.602, 1.856, 8.099, 4.793, 5.258, 1.948, 2.016, 1.72, 
    3.523, 5.142, 5.03, 17.116, 7.487, 7.235, 8.407, 3.585, 3.04, 
    4.506, 4.026, 10.015, 3.807, 8.342, 4.873, 4.21, 5.79, 20.031, 
    3.12, 4.239, 42.889, 18.702, 19.384, 19.981, 23.454, 18.292, 
    62.969, 19.677, 25.142, 55.025, 30.228, 20.731, 18.017, 22.562, 
    8.579, 8.663, 17.277, 7.495, 7.351, 38.814, 24.896, 30.968, 
    39.639, 39.108, 18.909, 65.557, 56.319, 32.419, 7.28, 2.734, 
    1.494, 5.23, 4.252, 1.923, 9.488, 2.662, 1.644, 6.813, 8.478, 
    6.799, 33.731, 13.292, 10.854, 12.287, 3.597, 4.815, 33.283, 
    7.684, 8.271, 37.239, 9.026, 9.107, 38.36, 28.966, 32.334, 
    2.691, 2.737, 2.949, 3.163, 4.345, 5.337, 5.419, 9.01, 8.911, 
    1.155, 0.485, 0.863, 5.354, 0.697, 1.304, 4.537, 2.098, 1.517
    )), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 135L, 136L, 
137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 159L, 160L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 
166L, 167L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 195L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 
202L, 203L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 231L, 232L, 
233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 
247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 
261L, 262L, 263L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 
275L), class = "data.frame")
```

Model:

```
mod.lmer <- lmer(value ~ Status + Treatment + Stim + Treatment*Status*Stim + (1|Subject),
                  data = test2)
```

Notably, the following things do not produce similar results:

- anova() type 3 and Anova() type 3
- summary() and anova() type 3

I have tried `options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))` and it does not change any results. I have run my pre-determined contrasts of interest using emmeans, which had high significance, so I'm having a hard time understanding why the Anova() type 3 and summary() aren't showing any significance/similar results. I was initially going to use type 3 Anova for my data due to the contrasts I'm interested in and mildly unbalanced data, but now I'm not sure which anova to use for my report.

```
> anova(mod.lmer, type = 1)
Type I Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                       Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Status                 213.07  106.53     2  19.999  2.7098 0.0909098 .  
Treatment             1796.00  898.00     2 147.061 22.8417 2.298e-09 ***
Stim                   622.26  311.13     2 147.647  7.9139 0.0005433 ***
Status:Treatment       549.26  137.32     4 147.067  3.4928 0.0093286 ** 
Treatment:Stim         584.18  146.04     4 147.072  3.7148 0.0065363 ** 
Status:Stim            385.45   96.36     4 147.755  2.4511 0.0486018 *  
Status:Treatment:Stim   59.95    7.49     8 147.088  0.1906 0.9918876    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> anova(mod.lmer, type = 3)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                       Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Status                 217.10  108.55     2  20.041  2.7611  0.087273 .  
Treatment             1837.07  918.53     2 147.097 23.3640 1.543e-09 ***
Stim                   523.71  261.86     2 147.852  6.6606  0.001699 ** 
Status:Treatment       564.47  141.12     4 147.093  3.5895  0.007990 ** 
Treatment:Stim         624.52  156.13     4 147.093  3.9713  0.004331 ** 
Status:Stim            387.16   96.79     4 147.777  2.4620  0.047779 *  
Status:Treatment:Stim   59.95    7.49     8 147.088  0.1906  0.991888    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> Anova(mod.lmer, type = 3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: value
                       Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
(Intercept)           1.7023  1     0.1920
Status                0.8426  2     0.6562
Treatment             0.2184  2     0.8966
Stim                  0.4451  2     0.8005
Status:Treatment      3.2780  4     0.5124
Treatment:Stim        3.2279  4     0.5204
Status:Stim           2.6306  4     0.6214
Status:Treatment:Stim 1.5248  8     0.9923
```

Summary:

```
> summary(mod.lmer)
    Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
    Formula: value ~ Status + Treatment + Stim + Treatment * Status * Stim +      (1 | Subject)
       Data: test2

REML criterion at convergence: 1196.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0551 -0.3745  0.0005  0.2780  3.6174 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 74.54    8.634   
 Residual             39.31    6.270   
Number of obs: 194, groups:  Subject, 23

Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                   4.89297    3.75025  48.48368   1.305    0.198
StatusSub                     2.39119    5.92696  56.30030   0.403    0.688
StatusCl                      5.05503    5.50718  43.78039   0.918    0.364
TreatmentV2                  -0.15767    3.25774 147.17807  -0.048    0.961
TreatmentV1                  -1.36205    3.25774 147.17807  -0.418    0.676
StimC                         1.70903    3.18599 147.39224   0.536    0.592
StimD                        -0.06519    3.18599 147.39224  -0.020    0.984
StatusSub:TreatmentV2        -0.81671    5.34245 147.25141  -0.153    0.879
StatusCl:TreatmentV2          0.27653    4.67391 147.10108   0.059    0.953
StatusSub:TreatmentV1         1.22546    5.23640 147.42567   0.234    0.815
StatusCl:TreatmentV1          7.13076    4.67391 147.10108   1.526    0.129
TreatmentV2:StimC            -0.34855    4.39879 147.11046  -0.079    0.937
TreatmentV1:StimC             6.53316    4.39879 147.11046   1.485    0.140
TreatmentV2:StimD            -0.19866    4.39879 147.11046  -0.045    0.964
TreatmentV1:StimD             4.00316    4.39879 147.11046   0.910    0.364
StatusSub:StimC              -3.95019    5.11692 147.69916  -0.772    0.441
StatusCl:StimC               -1.28903    4.62419 147.20128  -0.279    0.781
StatusSub:StimD              -0.97558    5.24777 148.10277  -0.186    0.853
StatusCl:StimD                4.74162    4.62419 147.20128   1.025    0.307
StatusSub:TreatmentV2:StimC   1.71993    6.96497 147.15964   0.247    0.805
StatusCl:TreatmentV2:StimC    2.77555    6.46642 147.06631   0.429    0.668
StatusSub:TreatmentV1:StimC   6.14800    6.88397 147.25849   0.893    0.373
StatusCl:TreatmentV1:StimC    4.09084    6.46642 147.06631   0.633    0.528
StatusSub:TreatmentV2:StimD   0.66771    7.09809 147.15476   0.094    0.925
StatusCl:TreatmentV2:StimD    4.43823    6.46642 147.06631   0.686    0.494
StatusSub:TreatmentV1:StimD   4.23759    7.01862 147.24976   0.604    0.547
StatusCl:TreatmentV1:StimD    2.84270    6.46642 147.06631   0.440    0.661

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 27 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it
```

Comment: It's not enough to just change that contrasts option. You have to re-fit the model afterward. Did you do that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the same results you do from `car::Anova`. I have:

```
> options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
> mod.lmer <- lmer(value ~ Status + Treatment + Stim + Treatment*Status*Stim + (1|Subject),
+                  data = test2)

> car::Anova(mod.lmer, type=3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: value
                        Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
(Intercept)           29.8855  1  4.583e-08
Status                 5.5222  2   0.063224
Treatment             46.7280  2  7.131e-11
Stim                  13.3213  2   0.001280
Status:Treatment      14.3580  4   0.006236
Treatment:Stim        15.8853  4   0.003177
Status:Stim            9.8479  4   0.043068
Status:Treatment:Stim  1.5248  8   0.992289
```

... for which the P values are in the same ballpark as what you show with `anova(mod.lmer, type = 3)`. [BTW, if I try `anova(mod.lmer, type = 3)`, I get a warning message that there is no `type` argument; so you must have some package loaded that I don't have loaded. So please tell us where you are getting that `anova()` function.]

I suspect that the contrasts being used may not be what you think they are. The `contrasts` option requires two arguments, as in my test. Check the contrasts actually used in fitting the model as follows:

```
> attr(mod.lmer@pp$X, "contrasts")
$Status
[1] "contr.sum"

$Treatment
[1] "contr.sum"

$Stim
[1] "contr.sum"
```

Another way of getting a type III anova that does not depend on what contrast coding is used is via `joint_tests()`:

```
> emmeans::joint_tests(mod.lmer)
 model term            df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
 Status                  2  19.89   2.761 0.0875 
 Treatment               2 147.06  23.363 <.0001 
 Stim                    2 147.75   6.654 0.0017 
 Status:Treatment        4 147.03   3.589 0.0080 
 Status:Stim             4 147.39   2.461 0.0478 
 Treatment:Stim          4 147.03   3.971 0.0043 
 Status:Treatment:Stim   8 147.02   0.191 0.9919
```

You can't directly compare the results of `summary()` with an ANOVA, because the summary provides tests of individual coefficients, not omnibus tests.

I don't think type III anovas are particularly useful. For model selection, type II anovas make sense; but type III tests consider things like main effects when two- and three-way interactions involving them are still in the model, and that's like testing the performance of your VW Rabbit, assuming that it is a Maserati.